# Automating a TortoiseSVN Relocate

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm in the process of moving my SVN repository from one server to another. As part of this process, I have a number of client PCs running TortoiseSVN that currently point to the old location which need to be updated for the new path. Not all of these are under my direct control, so I would like to create a small batch script to do the work for me.

As I understand it, SVN allows for a Unix-like implementation of the relocate as shown below.

```
svn switch --relocate From_URL To_URL
```

I'm not aware of how to perform this action using TortoiseSVN under Windows. The closest I can find uses the `/command:relocate` switch.

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:relocate /path:File_Path
```

This is a start, but it still prompts the end user to enter the new server path, which is something I would really like to avoid.

Is there a way to specify the new server name as an argument to `TortoiseProc.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me well, svn (the command-line client) is included in the TortoiseSVN binary distribution, so you should be able to get away with a simple batch file doing an

```
svn switch --relocate
```

Comment: Running as a batch file returns

"'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Maybe the path to svn isn't included in the %PATH%? I can use svn from cmd, and I don't recall explicitly installing the command line client...

Comment: It looks like svn command line tools were not installed. After installing, I'm able to call from the command line. My concern is that I won't have the command line tools installed on the remote PCs, so I'm afraid this won't be an option.

Comment: FYI: `svn.exe` is not installed by default by TortoiseSVN: it is an option during installation and is unchecked by default.